# Log into Google Cloud VM with as specific user using IAM

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-iam

I created a VM with an Ubuntu 22.04 image and I log in using IAM credentials, not SSH keys, for example:

`gcloud beta compute ssh --zone myzone vmname --project myproj --tunnel-through-iap`

My command prompt has the username I want.

I just created another VM and it is using my default username `ariel_balter_gmail_com`.

**I have no idea what I did with the first VM to make my username the one I want.**

On the first machine, I see:

```
(base) balter@???????:~$ ls /home
balter  ubuntu
```

and

```
(base) balter@????????:~$ cat /etc/passwd | grep balter
balter:x:1001:1002::/home/balter:/bin/bash
```

On the second machine I created a user "balter", and I see:

```
(base) ariel_balter_gmail_com@???????:~$ ls /home
ariel_balter_gmail_com  balter
```

```
(base) ariel_balter_gmail_com@??????:~$ cat /etc/passwd | grep balter
balter:x:1000:1001:,,,:/home/balter:/bin/bash
```

I did something different, and I have no idea what.

Comment: use this command `gcloud projects get-iam-policy MY_PROJECT` to list all Users and Service accounts in a project with their IAM roles, and Identify if the other account is also the Owner.

Comment: @JonB The only owner is `user:ariel.balter@gmail.com`.

Answer (score 1):

A Google Cloud IAM identity does not have the same format as a typical SSH Linux identity. Therefore separate home directories are created.

Your Linux machine has two users setup: `balter` and `ariel_balter_gmail_com`. The first was probably created as a Linux user for SSH and the other by Google Cloud. They are different identities as far a Linux is concerned.

You also cannot control the user identity string that IAM uses. It is created from the IAM email address.

Comment: I don't know of anything different I did setting up machines 1 and 2. Except, I added a `balter` user to machine 2 for my own convenience, and `su balter` as soon as I log in. Can you think of anything I might have done differently when I created the VMs?